# SQL or NoSQL for Mobile Application Development with Django

Tags: sql, django, nosql

We plan to develop a mobile application, typically iPhone and Android, as well as a Web site.  The server application will normally be developed with the great Django framework. In terms of features, the application will:

- Be multilingual
- Let users create their own inner-application. Basically, subscribe to modules to customize the web site features
- Let users customize the look and feel of the web application
- Hopefully deal with a high number of users :-)

With such features, our project seems to be fairly complex in terms of database relational schema. Because running on very low budget, we want te be agile and the relational database schema will be subject to change a fair amount of time.  If we use Django, it automatically comes with a very good SQL - ORM integration and Admin interface.

What would be your advice for our DBMS ?  Should we go with a SQL database (integrated with Django) and change the schema from time to time (painful ?) ? Or is worth it to go for NoSQL databases such as MongoDB and/or stop using Django ?

Thank a lot for your advices

Comment: Isn't SQLite the standard RDBMS they use with Android?

Comment: I'm actually talking of the database on the server side of my Mobile and Web application.  But you are right, on the client side, I will surely use SQLite for both Android and the iPhone.  However your comment raises a good reflexion on my side: If I will need an SQL schema on the client side anyway that will be a subset of the information contain on the server side database, am I forced to also use a SQL RDBMS on the server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "go with the one you are more experienced with, so that you can focus on getting things done instead of googling everything".

If you ask me - I choose NoSQL where applicable because **for me** it is simpler to setup, scale and use. I like Dynamo based solutions (for example Riak).

Comment: I finally choose to learn Node.js along with mongoDB.  The reason is that I tried for a while to make Django ORM work with a nonrel database, but that was a mistake.  Node.js with mongoDB is fast, scalable and just perfect for my need to built a RESTFUL API for mobile application.